# Calculate distance between two points directly in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, math

In my web/MySQL application I have something like this to get distance between two points:

```
6371 * acos(cos(radians(-19.83996)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(-43.94910) - radians(lng)) + sin(radians(-19.83996)) * sin(radians(lat)))
```

But I tested in SQLite and these mathematical functions (acos, cos, radians, sin) do not exist. Is there something equivalent for me to calculate the distance directly in the database?

However, I have an iPhone application that uses [this method](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=71) to calculate. Works perfectly, but now I need to perform this same search in the database in an Android application.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I have 9000 points to calculate distance and obtain the 5 nearby locations of a given point.

Comment: I don't got what you mean when you say ' I tested in SQLite and these mathematical functions (acos, cos, radians, sin) do not exist.'

Comment: Sorry, I meant when I was run this same code, I receive "Error: no such function: acos"

Comment: Do you really need the distances, or just the 5 nearest points?

Comment: I need the 5 nearest points. I used the distance because I thought it necessary for `order by` and `limit`.

Comment: Your "this method" link seems to be dead ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I would do:

Take your given point. Measure a (that is an arbitrary value to be refined) ~2km wide square around it and take the values for the east/west/north/south bounds.

Make a query for elements inside this square. This one is easy, you just have to

```
select * from points where lat between ? and ? and lon between ? and ?
```

Count your result. Not enough result (less than 5, obviously, but I would say twice that to be sure), retry with a larger radius. Too much (say, more than 100), try again with a smaller radius.

Once you have enough, load them, make sure all 5 elements you need are not only in the Xkm wide square, but also in the Xkm radius circle (to avoid having a potential closer element not detected by the previous approximation).

### Another approach

Valid only if your given point is relatively close to those you are searching.

Measure a local approximation of a flat earth. Close to your point, you can consider a linear relation between lat, lon, and distance. That allows you to make a request sorted by a simple calculus. (multiplication and addition). Again, select a little more points in order to make the proper calculation after the SQLite request.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I use this query too, but to find points in region, works perfectly. But now I need find the 5 nearest points in total amount of 9000 of my database.

Comment: i understand your request. What i suggest is a two part approach : an approximation to try a reduce the number of result to a minimum using sqlite queries, and a fine final filtering using java objects

Comment: How do I do that?  =/

"Measure a (that is an arbitrary value to be refined) ~2km wide square around it and take the values for the east/west/north/south bounds."

Comment: @CíceroMoura find the lat/lon of the corners of a shape that inscribes a 2km circle in it

Answer (score 7):

Insert  cos_lat_rad,sin_lat_rad,cos_lon_rad,sin_lon_rad  in to your table

```
contentValues.put("cos_lat_rad", Math.cos(deg2rad(latitude)));
contentValues.put("sin_lat_rad", Math.sin(deg2rad(latitude)));
contentValues.put("cos_lon_rad", Math.cos(deg2rad(longitude)));
contentValues.put("sin_lon_rad", Math.sin(deg2rad(longitude)));
```

degree to radian

```
public static double deg2rad(double deg) {
    return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
}
```

query , distance in km

```
 Cursor c=database.dis(String.valueOf(Math.cos((double) distance / (double) 6380)), Math.cos(deg2rad(latitude)), Math.sin(deg2rad(latitude)), Math.cos(deg2rad(longitude)), Math.sin(deg2rad(longitude)));
```

query

```
public Cursor dis(String dis, double cos_lat_rad, double sin_lat_rad, double cos_lon_rad, double sin_lon_rad) {

    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * ,(" + sin_lat_rad + "*\"sin_lat_rad\"+" + cos_lat_rad + "*\"cos_lat_rad\"*(" + sin_lon_rad + "*\"sin_lon_rad\"+" + cos_lon_rad + "*\"cos_lon_rad\")) AS \"distance_acos\" FROM parish WHERE ("+sin_lat_rad+" * \"sin_lat_rad\" +"+ cos_lat_rad +"* \"cos_lat_rad\" * (+"+sin_lon_rad +"* \"sin_lon_rad\" + "+cos_lon_rad +"* \"cos_lon_rad\")) >"+dis+ " ORDER BY \"distance_acos\" DESC ", null);
    return cursor;

}
```

convert distance_acos to km

```
 if(c.moveToFirst())
        do {
            double distance_acos= c.getDouble(c.getColumnIndex("distance_acos"));
                     String Distance=String.valueOf(Math.acos(distance_acos) * 6380); 
        }while (c.moveToNext());
```

Answer (score 1):

For windows:

Install minGw full options. modify environment variable: system variable path, including

```
c:\mingw\bin
```

test functionality command:

```
g++ --version
```

copy files: extension-functions.c, sqlite3.h, sqlite3ext.h in sqlite3 program directory. Go to sqlite3 directory and compile:

```
gcc -shared -I "path" -o libsqlitefunctions.so extension-functions.c
```

(path = path of sqlite3ext.h; i.e. C:\sqlite3)

If the program is built so that loading extensions is permitted, the following will work:

```
   sqlite> SELECT load_extension('./libsqlitefunctions.so');

   sqlite> select cos(radians(45));

   0.707106781186548
```

SQLite Distance implementation:
From:  https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula

Distance

This uses the ‘haversine’ formula to calculate the great-circle distance between two points – that is, the shortest distance over the earth’s surface – giving an ‘as-the-crow-flies’ distance between the points (ignoring any hills they fly over, of course!).

Haversine

Formula:

```
a = sin²(Δφ/2) + cos φ1 * cos φ2 * sin²(Δλ/2)

c = 2 * atan2( √a, √(1−a) )
c = 2 * 
d = R * c
```

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km);

note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!

JavaScript:

```
const R = 6378136.6 ; // meters equatorial radius
const φ1 = lat1 * Math.PI/180; // φ, λ in radians
const φ2 = lat2 * Math.PI/180;
const Δφ = (lat2-lat1) * Math.PI/180;
const Δλ = (lon2-lon1) * Math.PI/180;

const a = Math.sin(Δφ/2) * Math.sin(Δφ/2) +
          Math.cos(φ1) * Math.cos(φ2) *
          Math.sin(Δλ/2) * Math.sin(Δλ/2);
const c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

const c = 2 * Math.asen(MIN (1, Math.sqrt(a))); //sqlite implementation

const d = R * c; // in metres

Distance = 2 * R * ASIN( MIN (1, SQRT( SIN( (RADIANS(lat1)-RADIANS(lat2))/2 )^2 + COS( RADIANS(lat1) )*COS( RADIANS(lat2) )*SIN( (RADIANS(long1)-RADIANS(long2))/2 )^2 )))
```

Physical Properties of Earth https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_ellipsoid :Ecuatorial radius: 6378.1366 Kms. Average radius: 6367 Kms

```
Constant = 2 * 6378136.6 = 12756273.2
```

SQLite query command with coordinates taken from table PAR:

```
ROUND (
      12756273.2 * ASIN(
                        MIN (1 , 
                                SQRT(
                                    POWER( SIN(RADIANS(PAR.Lat1 - PAR.Lat2)/2) , 2) + 
                                    COS(RADIANS(PAR.Lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(PAR.Lat2)) * POWER ( SIN(RADIANS(PAR.Long1 - PAR.Long2)/2) , 2)
                                      )
                            )
                        )
         , 0) AS Distance
```

Answer (score -1):

Reply of Angel does not solve the problem for SQLite since it still includes ACOS function which does not exist in SQLite

What I have concluded after a thorough research is that one should pick a rough estimation to use in SQLite with the formula below:

Distance estimation for km:

```
SQRT(SQUARE((TO_LAT-FROM_LAT)*110)+
     SQUARE((TO_LONG-FROM_LONG)*COS(TO_LAT)*111))
```

Answer (score -4):

In android we have a Location class, we need initialize the location class and in it we have a method called distanceBetween() which gives the distance between two geopoints.

Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I need calculate directly in SQLite, because I have 9000 point to calculate and obtain the 5 nearby locations. I believe it is the most effective way.