# Select locations based on distance between geocodes using SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, google-maps

I have an SQL database containing hotel information, some of which is the geocoded lat/lng generated by Googles geocoder.

I want to be able to select (directly using an SQL query) all the hotels within a certain range. This range will never be more than 50km so I dont need to go as detailed as alot of answers on here are suggesting (taking into account earth curvature and the fact its not a perfect sphere isnt an issue over the distances im searching).

Im thinking a simple Pythagorian formula would suffice, but I dont know what the latitude and longitude figures represent (and therefore how to convert to metres) and also ive read on a couple of 'simple' solutions to my problem that there are issues with their formulas and calculating distances between two locations either side of the meridian line (as I am based in London this will be a big issue for me!!)

Any help would be great, thankyou!

----Helpful Information-----

My database stores the geocoded data in the following format:

```
geo_lat: 51.5033630,
geo_lon; -0.1276250
```

Comment: Check this answer on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110565/distance-between-2-geocodes)

Comment: I saw that post, but they are either too complex for my use (ie taking into account the 'sphere factor') or they are not using the SQL query SELECT * WHERE... etc

Comment: Look at there these links 

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126404/calculate-distance-between-two-points-directly-in-sqlite

Comment: @giovanni i think this will help u

Comment: You can either calculate it yourself as others have said using Pythagoras' OR since you're already using google you can plot all your hotels on a google map then use circle overlays to show all markers within a distance something like this http://s14.postimg.org/sd5h4dcpd/Untitled.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a select clause that will get your distance into kilometers. From there you can use a where clause to filter it down to less than 25 kilometers or whatever you want. If you want it in miles just take off the * 1.609344 conversion.

```
$latitude = [current_latitude];
$longitude = [current_longitude];

SELECT
    ((((acos(sin((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * sin((`geo_lat`*pi()/180))+cos((".$latitude."*pi()/180)) * cos((`geo_lat`*pi()/180)) * cos(((".$longitude."- `geo_lon`)* pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) * 1.609344) as distance 
FROM
    [table_name]
WHERE distance
```

Comment: Excellent - exactly what I was after (although if im honest it is still quite a complex formula - I was hoping to be able to understand what it does :) ) And can this be used either side of the meridian line? ive read comparing -0.1 to +0.1 longitude throws up some large errors in some formulas!

Comment: I don't think the meridian line comes into effect. This is using geo locations. I suppose understanding it is a different story. This is a common way of doing it in SQL. I did not come up with the entire idea myself. It works great though. Please give up vote or mark it as the answer if you are happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple map projection and straight distances for example equirectangular projection. In the formula on this website you can also use a simplier formula without the square root:http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html. Of course you can use a bounding box to filter the query:[How to calculate the bounding box for a given lat/lng location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238260/how-to-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-a-given-lat-lng-location), https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19760/how-do-i-calculate-the-bounding-box-for-given-a-distance-and-latitude-longitude.