# Android sqlite how to calculate distance from latitude and longitude

Tags: java, android, sqlite, distance

I am calculating distance from latitude and longitude in sqlite in android. First I have to fetch coordinates from web service then I have to converted coordinates from degrees to radians using below code:

```
 Math.cos(deg2rad(outlet.getLatitude()))
 Math.sin(deg2rad(outlet.getLatitude()))
 public static double deg2rad(double deg) {
     return (deg * Math.PI / 180.0);
 }
```

then I have inserted it into my Table and then I am using this query to calculate the distance in sqlite. When I run this query:

```
SELECT "location",
(sin_lat_rad  "sin_lat_rad" + cos_lat_rad  "cos_lat_rad" *
 (sin_lon_rad  "sin_lon_rad" + cos_lon_rad  "cos_lon_rad"))
```

I am getting 0.99999999 in output [image: error]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i need to calculate distance from my current lat / long to destination lat / long

Comment: @Achin: You can use the Haversine algorithm http://stackoverflow.com/a/17787472/1878151

Comment: i want to calculate the distance using sqlite query

Comment: i am using this procedure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10126404/calculate-distance-between-two-points-directly-in-sqlite